# R Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `type`. x `f` must be a factor (or character vector)

Tags: r, dataframe, forcats

I'm having trouble with these errors in R... I don't know how to fix it.

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `type`.
x `f` must be a factor (or character vector).
i Input `type` is `fct_relevel(type, c("hit", "bad-hit [evalue > 0.01]", "non-hit"))`.

I'm pretty sure the code worked before with a different data set, but now it's generating these errors...

#Script to get to where I'm at (you may need to install biostrings)

```
BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
```

- 

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(data.table)

  a <- 
                  "qseqid      sseqid  pident       length mismatch gapopen qstart qend  sstart    send   ppos evalue bitscore
                  KQJ81400 NC_012870.2 100.000        10        0       0     1354 1383  49691442  49691471 100.00   0.33   25.3
                  KQJ81513 NC_012871.2 100.000        11        0       0     1288 1256  77518889  77518857 100.00   0.00   30.4"
    
    blasts <- read.table(text=a, header = TRUE)
     


BrachCDS <- Biostrings::readDNAStringSet('ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/plants/release-47/fasta/brachypodium_distachyon/cds/Brachypodium_distachyon.Brachypodium_distachyon_v3.0.cds.all.fa.gz') %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column(var='gene') %>% 
rename(seq=x) %>% as_tibble()
    
 c <-

    ">KQJ81400 cds chromosome:Brachypodium_distachyon_v3.0:5:440113:447844:-1 gene:BRADI_5g00478v3 gene_biotype:protein_coding 
    >KQJ81513 cds chromosome:Brachypodium_distachyon_v3.0:5:1105857:1107846:-1 gene:BRADI_5g01198v3 description:hypothetical protein"
    
    B1000 <-fread(c, header = F, fill= T, select =c(1,2))



blasts <- blasts %>% arrange(qseqid,-pident,evalue,-bitscore) %>%
distinct (qseqid, .keep_all = T) %>%
mutate(evalue=round(evalue,digits = 2)) %>%
rename(subject_length=length)
```

(I actually have my own CDS file which is in multiline fasta format with just the qseqid so I don't think that's the problem)

And then this is the part of the script I get an error with:

```
B1000_SEQ <- BrachCDS %>% filter(gene %in% B1000$V1) %>%
mutate(length=nchar(seq)) %>%
left_join(blasts, by=c('gene'='qseqid')) %>%
           mutate(type=ifelse(is.na(evalue),'non-hit',
                   ifelse(evalue <= 0.01,'hit','bad-hit [evalue > 0.01]')),
                             type=fct_relevel(type,c('hit','bad-hit [evalue > 0.01]','non-hit')))
```

What does it mean by 'f'? Where even is 'f' and why isn't it a factor? And what's going on with 'type'?
Any help into what's going on or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Solved it, see comments... my bad

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry!! I've added some data with a script that can run which is hopefully reproducible?

The desired output is just to have the B1000_SEQ file able to be used in a ggplot with qseqid in the blasts file being the genes, and evalues in the blast file determining whether something is a hit, non-hit or bad-hit based on the values (that part is probably correct)

Comment: NEVERMIND I SOLVED IT!!! I had to get rid of the ">" symbols in the B1000 dataset

Comment: Either delete your question or post the answer how you solved it